Struggling setting up VimR and VimTeX
I'm new to Vim, and I've downloaded VimR, and followed
https://ejmastnak.com/tutorials/vim-latex/vimtex/#appendix
https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/
to try setting up VimTeX.
:help vimtex successfully loads, and :PluginInstall also works, but :VimtexInfo does not, returning E492: Not an editor command: VimtexInfo.
My init.vim file is as follows
call plug#begin()

set encoding=utf-8

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'


call plug#end()

any help would be appreciated.

VimtexInfo is a command available only in buffers with associated filetype tex.  If you first do :set ft=tex<cr>, does it still throw an error?

I am surprised how easy that was. Thanks a lot.
